# Find matches in one list and remove them

Tags: java

I have one list in which I need to loop through the list and find matches in order to combine them and add them to another list. The problem is I keep having issues with iterating over some elements multiple times or skipping over certain elements.

The objects in the list each have two int values. If the first int value is a match between two elements, I need to combine both object's second int value and add that object to another list

If I have a list `((12,10), (13,10), (12,5), (14,5), (14,10), (10,20))`
I would like to combine the 12's and 14's into a new list to make
`((12,15), (14,15))` and my original list would be left with `((13,10), (10,20))`

I've tried using a for loop with and without an Iterator, but with no luck.

```
List<Record> finalList = new ArrayList<Record>();

for (int i = 0; i < tempAggregateList.size(); i++){
            Record record = tempAggregateList.get(i);
            for (int j = i+1; j < tempAggregateList.size(); j++){
                Record nextRecord = tempAggregateList.get(j);
                if (record.getFirstValue() == nextRecord.getFirstValue()){
                    record.setSecondValue(record.getSecondValue() + nextRecord.getSecondValue());
                    //then remove nextRecord from tempAggregateList
                }
            }
            finalList.add(record);
        }
```

The way I have it now, my first for loop will loop over elements that I've already combined and added to `finalList`. It'd be easiest to just remove elements that I've added to finalList , but I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: It is in no way clear how you want to filter, how do you get 12,15 and 14,15?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry it wasn't clear when saying "If the first int value is a match between two elements, I need to combine both object's second int value". So if two objects' first value both are 12, then I combine their second values (5 and 10) into one (15) and leave their first value as 12. It represents more of a key for the element.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but this sounds like a job for a map instead of a list. Do you need to use a list for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use streams:

```
// group by first value
Map<Integer, Record> newList = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Record::getFirstValue,
       // for each record list for the same first value, add the second one          
       Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            // add first and second value for each pair
            Collectors.reducing((r1, r2) -> new Record(r1.getFirstValue(), r1.getSecondValue() + r2.getSecondValue())),
            // there will be no empty list, so all optionals will be present
            Optional::get));
```

Now you have a `Map<Integer, Record>` with the keys being the first value and the key being the combined `Record`.

EDIT: I realized this could be done somewhat easier by

```
BinaryOperator<Record> addRecords = (r1, r2) -> new Record(r1.getFirstValue(), r1.getSecondValue() + r2.getSecondValue());

Map<Integer, Record> map = list.stream().collect(
    toMap(Record::getFirstValue, r -> r, addRecords));
```

and if you want a list and do this in one line

```
List<Record> result = list.stream().collect(
    collectingAndThen(
        toMap(Record::getFirstValue, r -> r, addRecords),
        m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

Static import from `Collectors` are implied.

Comment: I edited the answer to get it to compile, but unfortunately the solution does not produce the result I am looking for. The list stays the same

Comment: @Drew13 did you use `list = new ArrayList<>(result.valueSet())`?

Comment: @Drew13 I added a somewhat easier construct.

Answer (score 1):

After finalList.add(record), simple add tempAggregateList.remove(i);

Comment: @vilpe89 how does it crush? and why? I executed and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Well maybe it's not crashing but it sure is not working right. If you remove from index i=2, then after that it's needed to do --i because we need to iterate the new [2]. If you don't do --i then the 'for' will do ++i (now i=3) and skip one item (which is now at i=2)...

Answer (score 0):

This uses `groupingBy` to get a `List` of `List`. if the `List` has a length greater than one it is added to the final List. if the `List`has a length equal to 1, it is kept in the original `List`.

```
List<Record> originalList = new ArrayList();
originalList.add(new Record(12, 10));
originalList.add(new Record(13, 10));
originalList.add(new Record(12, 5));
originalList.add(new Record(14, 5));
originalList.add(new Record(14, 10));
originalList.add(new Record(10, 20));

List<Record> finalList = originalList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Record::getFirstValue)).values().stream().filter((t) -> {
    return t.size() > 1; 
}).flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().collect(groupingBy(Record::getFirstValue, Collectors.summingInt(Record::getSecondValue))).entrySet().stream().map(t -> new Record(t.getKey(), t.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
finalList.forEach((t) -> {
    System.out.println("(" + t.getFirstValue() + ", " + t.getSecondValue() + ")");
});

originalList = originalList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Record::getFirstValue)).values().stream().filter((t) -> {
    return t.size() == 1;
}).flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList()).stream().collect(groupingBy(Record::getFirstValue, Collectors.summingInt(Record::getSecondValue))).entrySet().stream().map(t -> new Record(t.getKey(), t.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());

originalList.forEach((t) -> {
    System.out.println("(" + t.getFirstValue() + ", " + t.getSecondValue() + ")");
});
```

> output

```
(12, 15)
(14, 15)
(10, 20)
(13, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, iterations, a `Set` to store the indices to be removed, and reverse iteration for removing the items from the initial list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Record> tempAggregateList = new ArrayList<Record>();
    tempAggregateList.add(new Record(12, 10));
    tempAggregateList.add(new Record(13, 10));
    tempAggregateList.add(new Record(12, 5));
    tempAggregateList.add(new Record(14, 5));
    tempAggregateList.add(new Record(14, 10));
    tempAggregateList.add(new Record(10, 20));

    List<Record> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < tempAggregateList.size(); i++) {
        if (!set.contains(i)) {
            Record record = tempAggregateList.get(i);
            int baseValue = record.getFirstValue();
            int sum = record.getSecondValue();
            boolean found = false;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < tempAggregateList.size(); j++) {
                Record nextRecord = tempAggregateList.get(j);
                if (nextRecord.getFirstValue() == baseValue) {
                    found = true;
                    set.add(i);
                    set.add(j);
                    sum += nextRecord.getSecondValue();
                }
            }
            if (found)
                finalList.add(new Record(baseValue, sum));
        }
    }

    for (int i = tempAggregateList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (set.contains(i))
            tempAggregateList.remove(i);
    }

    for (Record r : tempAggregateList) {
        System.out.print("(" + r.getFirstValue() + ", " + r.getSecondValue() + ") ");
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (Record r : finalList) {
        System.out.print("(" + r.getFirstValue() + ", " + r.getSecondValue() + ") ");
    }
}
```

will print:

```
(13, 10) (10, 20) 
(12, 15) (14, 15)
```